# Как сделать обновление значения в базе?

Tags: php, yii

В базе данных есть таблица с полями id и Name.
На странице добавляю новый значения в базу через форму, которая отправляет значения в модель, а дальше в базу.
Вот форма:

```
<?= $form->field($addform, 'nameEx')->textInput()->label('Exercise name')?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Отправить', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>
```

Добавление работает.
А как организовать обновление значения в базе?
Например я добавил значение, но хочу заменить Name, как это сделать? Без использования генератора Yii

Начал делать так:

```
<?php foreach ($allNameEx as $item){ ?>

    <?= $form->field($addform, 'nameEx')->textInput(array('value'=>$item['name']))->label('');?>

    <a href="<?php echo Url::toRoute(['site/ex-delete', 'id' => $item['id']]) ?>" >Удалить</a>

<?php } ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Отправить', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Добавляю форму с input  в котором уже есть записанное значение Name, но что делать дальше? Ведь форма одна и принимает значение nameEx одно, соответственно при изменении изменятся все на одно значение.

Comment: выложите код контроллера и я все поясню

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте hidden поле, содержащее primary key таблицы и по нему модель будет обновляться.

Comment: Работает для одного значения в форме, это отлично, а если у меня много значений в форме, им нужно задать разные name(которые так же прописаны должны быть в модели формы) как автоматизировать?

Comment: Тогда можно представить результаты заполнения формы массивом. Для этого name у input должен быть вида name="name[$id]". В таком случае $_GET['name'] будет выглядеть как массив, где ключ массива будет id элемента, а значение - текст, который ввел пользователь. Посмотрите документацию к ActiveForm что бы понять, как в параметрах задать name для input. hiddenField в таком случае не понадобится.